# Reverse proxying websockets based on $arg_name (URL Query String Parameter)

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy

I had `nginx` working with my websocket server using the following:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name streams.domain.com;
    location / {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
        proxy_pass http://192.168.1.52:80;
    }
}
```

However, I need to change the destination based on a querystring parameter.  I changed it to the following:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name streams.domain.com;
    location / {
        if ( $arg_serverId = 1562182 ) { 
            return 101 http://192.168.1.52:80; 
        }
    }
}
```

Now I get the error `Error during WebSocket handshake: 'Upgrade' header is missing`

So I tried using `add_header` but with the configuration below I just get `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name streams.domain.com;
    location / {
        if ( $arg_serverId = 1562182 ) { 
            add_header 'Upgrade' $http_upgrade;
            add_header 'Connection' $connection_upgrade;
            return 101 http://192.168.1.52:80; 
        }
    }
}
```

So how can I use `$arg_` conditons and pass the Upgrade headers necessary for websockets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up getting it to work with `map`.  With a URL like `http://stream.domain.com?serverId=1001` the following works great:

```
http {
    map $arg_serverId $streamdestination {
        1001 http://192.168.1.52:80; 
        1002 http://192.168.1.51:80; 
        1003 http://192.168.1.50:80; 
    }
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name streams.domain.com;
        location / {
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_pass $streamdestination;
        }
    }
}
```